# r, ggplot2, shape/colour. What is the difference between them?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(123)

library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dat=data.table(data.frame(a=rnorm(12),b=rnorm(12),c=rep(c(1,2),6),d=rep(c(1,2,3,4),3)))

ggplot(dat,aes(a,c,colour=d)) + geom_point() # line 1

ggplot(dat,aes(a,c,shape=d)) + geom_point() # line 2
```

Why is line 1 working but not line 2 ? Isn't it just a difference of how the plots are lookink ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you what's wrong:

```
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
```

`shape` needs a factor:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(a,c,shape=factor(d))) + geom_point()
```

Also check how `ggplot(dat,aes(a,c,colour=factor(d))) + geom_point()` (a discrete colour scale) looks compared to the continuous colour scale.

Comment: An alternative to convert the continuous variable into a factor is  `cut`.